# ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, alter

I'm using Oracle 12c, while tried to alter the datatype from `NUMBER(8,0)` to `VARCHAR2(10)` facing error like below:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype
01439. 00000 -  "column to be modified must be empty to change datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Note: Column Drop and recreation take lots of time because it has 6 months of data.

Can someone suggest alternative way to change the datatype to `varchar(10)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pay the price, somehow, as there's no such thing as a free lunch.

Here are a few examples; sample table whose salary column is `varchar2(10)`:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2  select ename, cast(sal as varchar2(10)) sal
  3  from emp
  4  where rownum <= 5;

Table created.
```

Create a "copy" with `sal` column modified to `number`:

```
SQL> create table test_new as
  2  select ename, to_number(sal) sal
  3  from test;

Table created.
```

Drop the original table (I understand that you might not be able to do that if it is e.g. referenced by other tables):

```
SQL> drop table test;

Table dropped.
```

Rename new tables to its original name:

```
SQL> rename test_new to test;

Table renamed.
```

And that's it; the result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
SMITH             800
ALLEN            1600
WARD             1250
JONES            2975
MARTIN           1250

SQL> desc test;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 SAL                                                NUMBER

SQL>
```

---

Another option, if you can't afford dropping the original table:

```
SQL> drop table test;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table test as
  2  select ename, cast(sal as varchar2(10)) sal
  3  from emp
  4  where rownum <= 5;

Table created.

SQL> desc test;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 SAL                                                VARCHAR2(10)
```

Modifying its datatype won't work because it isn't empty (as you already know):

```
SQL> alter table test modify sal number;
alter table test modify sal number
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype
```

So: add a new column whose datatype is `number` and put "old" salary values into it:

```
SQL> alter table test add new_sal number;

Table altered.

SQL> update test set new_sal = to_number(sal);

5 rows updated.
```

Now, drop the original column:

```
SQL> alter table test drop column sal;

Table altered.
```

Rename newly added column to its original name:

```
SQL> alter table test rename column new_sal to sal;

Table altered.
```

The result:

```
SQL> select * From test;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
SMITH             800
ALLEN            1600
WARD             1250
JONES            2975
MARTIN           1250

SQL> desc test;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 SAL                                                NUMBER

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively:

```
SQL> drop table test;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table test as
  2  select ename, cast(sal as varchar2(10)) sal
  3  from emp
  4  where rownum <= 5;

Table created.
```

Add a new column whose datatype is `number` and put "old" salary values into it:

```
SQL> alter table test add new_sal number;

Table altered.


SQL> update test set new_sal = to_number(sal);

5 rows updated.
```

Clear the original column's contents so that you could change its datatype (as it'll now be *empty*):

```
SQL> update test set sal = null;

5 rows updated.

SQL> alter table test modify sal number;

Table altered.
```

Put values back in there:

```
SQL> update test set sal = new_sal;

5 rows updated.
```

Drop the newly added column:

```
SQL> alter table test drop column new_sal;

Table altered.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
SMITH             800
ALLEN            1600
WARD             1250
JONES            2975
MARTIN           1250

SQL> desc test;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 SAL                                                NUMBER

SQL>
```

---

I can't tell which option is faster. For small tables, it doesn't really matter. How many rows do you have in that table? You said "6 months", but that doesn't really help.